# Joining Tables to Get Sums - SQL/Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am create an Access database at work for our call center. Right now there are four tables:

MASTERTABLE: DisplayName, CLOCKid (PrimaryKey), PHONEid

ROSTERTABLE: CLOCKid (ForeignKey), StartDate, EndDate

PHONELOG: PHONEid, DateStamp, StatusHours

TIMECLOCK: CLOCKid, DateStamp, HoursByDay

The Mastertable has one row for each unique employee. It contains each employee's various IDs/usernames for things listed above and other items. The Rostertable contains a row for each employee's position--an employee can have multiple positions over time, indicated by StartDate and EndDate, thus multiple rows. This is so we keep a historical record we can query. The PhoneLog is fed in from our phone system. It has multiple lines per user, representing each phone status the the amount of time the user spent in the status. The TimeClock is similar; An employee will have one row per day worked.

I need to create a query in Microsoft Access 2013, preferably using SQL, that will give me the Sum of everyone's TimeClock hours within their rostertable start/end times as well as the same for their phone hours. So the resulting query will list each employee from the RosterTable, the sum of their phone time, and the sum of their paid time.

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if anyone has questions/need clarification.

Comment: Example data?  What have you tried so far?  Most users here will not write the code for you, but gladly figure out what is wrong with your attempt.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MT.DisplayName, Sum(PL.StatusHours) as PhoneHours, Sum(TC.HoursByDay) as PaidTime
FROM MASTERTABLE MT
INNER JOIN ROSTERTABLE RT
  ON MT.ClockID = RT.ClockID
LEFT JOIN PHONELOG PL
  ON MT.PhoneID = PL.PhoneID
LEFT JOIN TIMECLOCK TC
  ON MT.ClockID = TC.ClockID
WHERE RT.StartDate >= YourStartDate
  AND RT.EndDate =< YourEndDate
```

You just have to define YourStartDate and YourEndDate, which could be text boxes on a form or input boxes in a query, or even inner joined from another table.